# How to use Sum and Inner Join in a delete statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table called `TableName` which I want to `delete` from all rows that `SUM` of their product quantity is less than 2.
I need to `inner join` table `oc_order_product` and `SUM` the values having the same `product_id` then use this `SUM` value in where clause to `delete` all rows with `SUM` less than 2.
I am using the following query right now:

```
  Delete TablenName from TablenName
        INNER JOIN oc_order_product 
                     ON oc_order_product.product_id = TablenName.product_id
   where oc_order_product.quantity HAVING SUM(oc_order_product.quantity) < 2;
```

Which I am getting the following error:

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'HAVING SUM(oc_order_product.quantity) < 2' at line 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If you need to do aggregation, you need to do it before the `join`:

```
Delete t
    from TablenName t join
         (select op.product_id, sum(op.quantity) as sumquantity
          from oc_order_product op
          group by op.product_id
         ) op
         on op.product_id = t.product_id and op.sumquantity < 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, Also can you tell me if I can add `WHERE oc_order_status.order_status_id IN ('3','5','17','19','20','23','25','26','29') `to the above statement. Sorry I just figured out I need this one as well, I can add it to the question if you like.

Comment: @Schwann . . . Because that involves a third table, you should ask another question.

Comment: I did edit this question and posted a new question for that with the following link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861288/how-to-use-sum-and-inner-join-in-a-delete-statement-and-add-a-third-table-to-it], I would appreciate an answer on that one.

Comment: I just noticed this query is deleting all the items with quantity of 2 or less, but it should delete all the items with SUM of the quantity less than 2, can you please help?

Comment: This should be deleting all rows where the sum is less than 2.  If you want 2 or less, then use `<=`.

Comment: It is deleting quantity<2 but it should be deleting SUM quantity<2