# How to use Sum and Inner Join in a delete statement and add a third table to it

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This question is an addition to the following question answered here
[How to use Sum and Inner Join in a delete statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857172/how-to-use-sum-and-inner-join-in-a-delete-statement)

I will need to add the following where statement `WHERE oc_order_status.order_status_id IN ('3','5','17','19','20','23','25','26','29')` to the following query:

```
Delete t
    from TablenName t join
         (select op.product_id, sum(op.quantity) as quantity
          from oc_order_product op
          group by op.product_id
         ) op
         on op.product_id = t.product_id and op.quantity < 2;
```

All tables share the same `product_id` column with same values and all tables are in the same database.

Comment: How `oc_order_status` is related to `oc_order_product `

Comment: @JibinBalachandran they share the same product_id column and they are both in the same database, I will edit the question and add this explanation

Comment: order_status_id is varchar or int??

Comment: Totally subjective, but I find a `with` clause the prefilters such a conditional delete to be very readable.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran, it is `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `inner join` of product and status table using the FK `product_id`  and filter out the `order_status_id` in the where clause.

```
Delete t
    from TablenName t join
         (select op.product_id, sum(op.quantity) as quantity
          from oc_order_product op
          inner join oc_order_status os on os.product_id =op.product_id
          where os.order_status_id IN (3,5,17,19,20,23,25,26,29)
          group by op.product_id
         ) op
         on op.product_id = t.product_id and op.quantity < 2;
```

Comment: I get #1054 - Unknown column `os.product_id` in `on clause`, also `order_status_id` is `int`

Comment: @Schwann You told that `oc_order_status` is having column `product_id`. If so, it can be accessed using the table alias `os.product_id`. If there's a difference in the name in the `oc_order_status` table, update the same in join condition. Cross check the column name in both the tables.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it was a typo, fixed it and it worked great, thank you very much